# Spring Boot, Security and OAuth2 - mobile app backend

Tags: android, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, mobile-application

I am trying to protect my rest service which is a backend to my Android and iOS application. I want protect all endpoints on this service to allow to communicate only with my mobile application.

I figure out this flow (i am not sure if it is correct):

1. Secure all endpoints by Basic Authentication header with client_id:client secret (standard way - in authorization header, base64 format). Those endpoints will be for not logged in users.
2. Secure part of the endpoints using OAuth2. Those endpoints will be for logged in users.

Unfortunatelly i do not know how to apply that flow. I created confguration mentioned bellow but its not working as i expected.

So, two questions:

1. Is this flow correct and possible with spring security and oauth?
2. How to apply this flow in my configuration.

Security config:

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private String securityRealm = "MyRealm";

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user").authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().realmName(securityRealm)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Authorization config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String clientId = "clientid";
    private final String clientSecret = "clientsecret";
    private final String grantType = "password";
    private final String scopeRead = "read";
    private final String scopeWrite = "write";
    private final String resourceIds = "resourcesId";

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(clientId).secret(clientSecret)
            .authorizedGrantTypes(grantType, "refresh_token", "client_credential")
            .scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite)
            .resourceIds(resourceIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore(){
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }
}
```

And Resources server:

```
@Order(2)
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String resourceIds = "resourcesId";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources
            .resourceId(resourceIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/places").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/places/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/welcome/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: ...antMatchers("/non-loggedin-users").access("#oauth2.isClient()") and ...antMatchers("/loggedin-users").access("hasRole('ROLE_YYY')")

Comment: I removed Order annotation and added this: .antMatchers("/user").access("#oauth2.isClient()") to my ResourcesServer config and now all requests need access token. It is not what i need.

Comment: Then add .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()(as you already doing in above class), and add .antMatchers("/welcome").authenticated().and().httpBasic() in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extended class

Comment: I tryied that what you said but without success. Is it possible to configure all endpoints with client-id and client secret, and part of requests using also access-token? Both information are always provided in Authorization header, and it cannot contais those two information.